# How to trace snmp trap sent by client process?

Tags: linux, rhel, trap, snmp, wireshark

We have a process(should be a client program) on RHEL 7.4 that send snmp traps to a Solaris server that has trap receiver process(should be a server program listening on 162/1691) on other machine(with IP 10.xx.xx.xx)

I have ssh access to RHEL box

---

Can I install some tracing tool on RHEL 7.4 to trace these snmp traps?

if yes, what is the process to trace the trap packets?

Comment: Did you tried tcpdump ?

Comment: @charith What are the arguments to pass with `tcpdump`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running this on your client machine ,You can use example below

```
tcpdump dst 10.xx.xx.xx and port 162 and not arp
```

you can replace the IP suites to you and not arp part for exclude the arp. If you are running this on server side you can replace dst with src and client ip instead server ip